# flex, change the button image when mouse over/out

Tags: image, apache-flex, button

with following code, i have implemented the image change when mouse hover the button.
but the image name is hardcoded, which is specified in the style. how can make it parameterized?  i want to reuse this small utility with image name as input parameter.
all the image used(14 images in my case) will be included in the flex project. 
i am using flex 3

```
<mx:Style>  
    .myCustomButton {
        upSkin: Embed(source="jjyxfx.png");
        overSkin:Embed(source="cwgl.png");
       downSkin: Embed(source="cwgl.png");

    }
</mx:Style>

<mx:Button y="0" width="105" height="107" fillAlphas="[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]" x="0" fillColors="[#3AA2D9, #3AA2D9]" styleName="myCustomButton" useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can't parameterize CSS styles; so you'll have to set the styles via ActionScript:

```
public function setStylesOnButton(upSkinValue:String,overSkinValue:String,downSkinStyle:String):void{
  myButton.setStyle('upSkin',upSkinValue);
  myButton.setStyle('overSkin',overSkinValue);
  myButton.setStyle('downSkin',downSkinStyle);
}
```

Make sure your button has an ID so you can access it in ActionScript:

```
<mx:Button id="myButton" y="0" width="105" height="107" fillAlphas="[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]" x="0" fillColors="[#3AA2D9, #3AA2D9]" styleName="myCustomButton" useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true"/>
```

Comment: thanks for they reply. what the value(upskinValue) looks like? i tried some, but none of them works

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You set an upSkinValue in your original CSS.  It is a string.  It is no different setting that value in the code I supplied.